# Save an Image in localStorage from an URL fetched from an API

Tags: javascript, image, api, local-storage

**Save an Image in localStorage from an URL fetched from an API on Window load**

I'm making a chrome extension which displays an image from the NASA APOD [API](https://api.nasa.gov/), every time the user opens a new tab. I have achieved it pretty easily but there is one problem, when the user's device is not connected to the internet the image dosen't loads, so I want to save the image whenever the image is fetched for the first time and store it in local storage so that if the device goes offline I can use the already saved image and the screen dosen't appears blank.

The API give a new image everyday so I want to update the previous saved image with the new one whenever available.

Here is the simple JavaScript code:

```
  window.addEventListener("load", function () {
  //checking is the user is connected to the internet and show content respectively
  if (navigator.onLine) {
    // NASA API
    fetch(
      `https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=MY_KEY`
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = `url("${data.url}")`;
        })
      .catch((err) => console.log("Something's wrong with NASA API"));
}
//when the user is offline
else {
  /*THE CODE GOES HERE*/
}
```

I'm also using a Quote [API](https://github.com/lukePeavey/quotable) along with the Data() method to display a quote and time also.
I've seen many document and questions on stackoverflow also but they do not solve my problem.
The final product after HTML and CSS looks like this:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suS6u.jpg).

Here is my Github [repo](https://github.com/abhinnkrishn/Astrominia-Chrome-Extension) for the full code

I'm new to promises and pretty much new in javascript too, please help me, Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following to set the image in local storage:

```
localStorage.setItem("myImage", document.body.style.backgroundImage);
```

and you can get the image using:

```js
localStorage.getItem("myImage");
```

Since you want to save image offline, you can convert the image to base64 and save that to local storage and can use base64 converted image in CSS using:

```css
background-image:url("data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhUAA......");
```